# JQGrid, change row background color based on condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have the following jqgrid that uses the jquery ui theme imported to my master page.

```
  $("#shippingscheduletable").jqGrid({
            url: $("#shippingscheduleurl").attr('href'),
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            altRows: true,
            colNames: ['Dealer', 'Model', 'Invoice', 'Date', 'PO', 'Serial', 'Status', 'City', 'State', 'IsPaid', 'Promo', 'Carrier', 'Int Notes', 'Ord Notes', 'Terms'],
            colModel: [
     { name: 'Company', index: 'id', width: 125, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Model', index: 'Model', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Invoice', index: 'Invoice', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Date', index: 'OrderDate', width: 60, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Po', index: 'PONum', width: 75, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Serial', index: 'Serial', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Status', index: 'OrderStatus', width: 70, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 100, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 30, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'IsPaid', index: 'IsPaid', width: 30, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Promo', index: 'Promo', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Carrier', index: 'Carrier', width: 80, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'InternalNotes', index: 'InternalNotes', width: 110, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'OrderNotes', index: 'OrderNotes', width: 110, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Terms', index: 'Terms', width: 60, align: 'left' }
     ],
            pager: jQuery("#shippingschedulepager"),
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 150, 200],
            sortname: 'Company',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            height: '700px',
            multiselect: true
        });
```

I would like to change the row color for all rows that have a true value for the IsPaid Field. Is this possible? if so, how would I do this?
I have been researching custom formatting, but I am unsure if this is the correct approach, as I cannot find anything about changing the color of the back ground.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use formatter function :

like in this post

http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=2678

Comment: Great, thank you.It took me a bit to understand how he was doing it. But it makes sense now and does just what I need it to. Thanks for the link!! I did not experience the issues the original poster experienced, so no problems!

Answer (score 20):

Just for reference of others here is the completed code. I also found I needed to add another condition to change the color of the row. I needed to change the row color only when the paid field is true, and when the status is complete. This code shows that. It also fixed the problem of losing the formatting when the grid is reloaded when sorting the columns. I hope this helps someone else.

```
    var rowsToColor = [];
    jQuery(function () {
        $("#shippingscheduletable").jqGrid({
            url: $("#shippingscheduleurl").attr('href'),
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            altRows: true,
            colNames: ['Dealer', 'Model', 'Invoice', 'Date', 'PO', 'Serial', 'Status', 'City', 'State', 'Paid', 'Promo', 'Carrier', 'Int Notes', 'Ord Notes', 'Terms'],
            colModel: [
     { name: 'Company', index: 'id', width: 125, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Model', index: 'Model', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Invoice', index: 'Invoice', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Date', index: 'OrderDate', width: 60, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Po', index: 'PONum', width: 75, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Serial', index: 'Serial', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Status', index: 'OrderStatus', width: 70, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 100, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 30, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Paid', index: 'IsPaid', width: 30, align: 'left', formatter: rowColorFormatter },
     { name: 'Promo', index: 'Promo', width: 50, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Carrier', index: 'Carrier', width: 80, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'InternalNotes', index: 'InternalNotes', width: 110, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'OrderNotes', index: 'OrderNotes', width: 110, align: 'left' },
     { name: 'Terms', index: 'Terms', width: 60, align: 'left' }
     ],
            pager: jQuery("#shippingschedulepager"),
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 150, 200],
            sortname: 'Company',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            height: '700px',
            multiselect: true,
            gridComplete: function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < rowsToColor.length; i++) {
                    var status = $("#" + rowsToColor[i]).find("td").eq(7).html();
                    if (status == "Complete") {
                        $("#" + rowsToColor[i]).find("td").css("background-color", "green");
                        $("#" + rowsToColor[i]).find("td").css("color", "silver");
                    }
                }
             }
        });
    });

    function rowColorFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        if (cellValue == "True")
            rowsToColor[rowsToColor.length] = options.rowId;
        return cellValue;
    }
```

so the formatter function adds the rowid that needs to be changed to an array if the paid value is true, then when the grid is complete it changes the css for each row id, after it checks the value of the 7th td which is where my status is found to make sure it is complete.

Answer (score 14):

I tried this and works to set the background color for the entire row. Works with paging also:

```
gridComplete: function()
{
    var rows = $("#"+mygrid).getDataIDs(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        var status = $("#"+mygrid).getCell(rows[i],"status");
        if(status == "Completed")
        {
            $("#"+mygrid).jqGrid('setRowData',rows[i],false, {  color:'white',weightfont:'bold',background:'blue'});            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This pointed me in the right direction but didnt quite work for me with paging. If it helps anyone, the following did work and doesn't use the colModel formatter.

I needed to apply a red colour to individual cells with outstanding amounts (name:os) in the 9th td on my grid. Datatype was json and I used the loadComplete function which has the data response as its parameter:

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
    $.each(data.rows,function(i,item){
        if(data.rows[i].os>0){
            $("#" + data.rows[i].id).find("td").eq(9).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
},
```

Got rid of the paging issues I had and works on sorting etc..

As an aside - I've found the loadComplete function useful for adding in dynamic information like changing the caption texts for search results - probably obvious to many but I'm new to json, jquery and jqgrid

Answer (score 4):

What about via Jquery Css.
See code below to set rows with Inactive status to red.
Grid name is `jqTable`.

```
setGridColors: function() {
    $('td[title="Inactive"]', '#jqTable').each(function(i) {
        $(this).parent().css('background', 'red');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To paint the grid, use the function below.  For example:   `PintarRowGrilla('#gridPreSeleccion', 3, 9, '#8FD9F1');`
9--> number of columns your grid:

```
function PintarRowGrilla(idGrilla, idrow, nrocolumnas, color)
{
    while(nrocolumnas > 0)
    {
        nrocolumnas--;
        jQuery(idGrilla).setCell(idrow, nrocolumnas, '', {
            'background-color': color
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the a simple JQuery selector and applied my wanted styles.
All you need is the uid (rowid) of the row you wish to apply the styles to.

```
if (!xCostCenter[i].saveSuccessful)
{  
    $("#row" + _updatedRowIDs[i] + "jqxgrid > div").css({ "background-color": "rgb(246, 119, 119)" });
}
```

In my case I wanted to change the color of rows that were not saved to change to a red color. 
To remove the color just execute the following.

```
$("#contenttablejqxgrid > div > div").css({ "background-color": "" });
```

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 loadComplete: function() {
    var ids = $(this).jqGrid("getDataIDs"), l = ids.length, i, rowid, status;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        rowid = ids[i];
    // get data from some column "ColumnName"
        varColumnName= $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "ColumnName");
    // or get data from some 
    //var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData', rowid);

    // now you can set css on the row with some
        if (varColumnName=== condition) {
            $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)).addClass('myAltRowClass');
         }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQGrid row event jqGridRowAttr for setting any formatting. For more detail see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/rowattr-triger-after-setrowdata Example steps to setting background are:

First set your custom CSS for conditional formatting inline or your CSS file. For example (Please see result in chrome browser)

```
.bg-danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
.bg-danger td{ background-color : #ff0000ad; }
```

Add row event right after ColModel

```
rowattr: function (rd) {

                    if (rd.FileExists == 'no') // your condition here
                    {
                        return { "class": "bg-danger" };
                    }

                }
```