# Color coding jqGrid based on sql retrieval, with sorting

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

The following is my color coding withing jqGrid :

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        var status = jQuery("#list2").getCell(rows[i],"status");
        if(status == "")
        {
            jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setRowData',rows[i],false, {  color:'white',weightfont:'bold',background:'red'});            
        }
        if(status == "Contacted")
        {
            jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setRowData',rows[i],false, {  color:'black',weightfont:'bold',background:'yellow'});            
        }
        if(status == "Scheduled")
        {
            jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setRowData',rows[i],false, {  color:'black',weightfont:'bold',background:'green'});            
        }
    }
```

I found out via useful comments how to color different columns certain colors, but also want to sort certain colors at the top, others at the bottom, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQGrid, change row background color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908171/jqgrid-change-row-background-color-based-on-condition)

Comment: @gforce301 My grid is layed out differently than this one, I am unsure on how to call on those external functions...

Comment: You can apply a sort method to sort the columns by status, which is equivalent to sort by color or you can apply a custom sort function for this purpose.