# jqgrid highlight maximum/minimum cell value from 1 page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

can jqgrid highlight maximum/minimum cell value from 1 page?

for example

```
Name  | Age

Alex  | 25

John  | 30 ----> Highlight this row

Peter | 29


page 1 > >>
```

Thank you for your help,

Best Regards,

Eka

Comment: It is good idea to search the stack here: Maybe [this can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908171/jqgrid-change-row-background-color-based-on-condition)

Comment: Hi Tony, how can i get the maximum value from column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formatter and get the maximum/minimum value in a cell and the index of that cell. Then, once the grid load is complete, you can add a class to the row that contains the maximum/minimum amount using the index. Here is an example of the solution:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
var mydata = [
        {id:"1",name:"Alex",age:25},
        {id:"2",name:"John",age:30},
        {id:"3",name:"Peter ",age:29}
        ];
    
 var currentMaxAmount = 0;
 var maxAmountIndex = -1;
 var currentIndex = 0;
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colModel:[
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'age',index:'age', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float",    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                
                if(parseInt(cellvalue) > currentMaxAmount)
                {
                    currentMaxAmount = parseInt(cellvalue);
                    maxAmountIndex = currentIndex;
                }
                currentIndex++;
                return cellvalue;
    
            }
        }   
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    data: mydata,
    loadComplete: function (gridData) {
        if(maxAmountIndex > -1)
            $($(".jqgrow")[maxAmountIndex]).addClass("highlighted");
    }
});

});
</script>
<style>
tr.highlighted > td{
background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Execuse me, I do not understand with your formatter logic. Where this number come from?                              
 var currentMaxAmount = 0;
 var maxAmountIndex = -1;
 var currentIndex = 0;                                                                                                           Can you help me explain this please?

Comment: var currentMaxAmount = 0; var maxAmountIndex = -1; var currentIndex = 0; Here i am initalizing the parameter to be used later.
The formatter function is executed on loading of each row. So logically, it is as if you are looping through the table and comparing the age of the current row with the current maximum amount. If the age in the current row is larger than the current maximum, then we replace the current maximum with the age and save the index of the row. On loadComplete, we have the index of the row containing the maximum age so we highlight it.